# asynchronous communication to thread from JOptionPane

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, asynchronous, joptionpane

I am trying to figure out how to set a variable from a `JOptionPane` to a main thread that is running.  Based on the results of the `JOptionPane` dialog this would affect some logic in that main thread.  Here is a an rough example:

```
public class MainThread {       
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        Timer timer = new Timer();    
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), 0, 1000);           
    }    
}

public class MyTask extends TimerTask {    
    int x = 0;
    AsyncPopUp popUp = new AsyncPopUp();

    public void run() {         
        // code to detect reset here
        // x = 0;    
        x++;
        System.out.println(x);          
        if (x==10){
            new AsyncPopUp().showMessage();
        }    
    }    
}

public class AsyncPopUp {    
    void showMessage() {    
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {    
            @Override
            public void run() {    
                int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Reset Counter?",
                               "Question", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                if (response == 0){                     
                    System.out.println("Send Message to task to reset");
                }                                   
            }    
        });         
        t.start();    
    }    
}
```

I am probably going about this the wrong way.  Perhaps I should be using a `JPanel` with `ActionListener`?  Or a `SwingWorker`?

Thanks.

**I think this may work -- Let me know if this is bad practice:**

```
public class Async {
    private Boolean response = false;
    private Thread t;

    public void start() {
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {    
            int x = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {    
                System.out.println(x);

                if (x == 10) {
                    t = new Thread(new DoTask());
                    t.start();
                }

                if (response == true) {
                    System.out.println("true");
                    x = 0;
                    response = false;

                } else {
                    System.out.println("false");
                }    
                x++;    
            }

        }, 0, 1000);    
    }

    public class DoTask implements Runnable {    
        @Override
        public void run() {    
            int optionResponse = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                    "Reset Counter?","Question", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (optionResponse == 0) {
                response = true;
            }    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?  The code you've posted will (assuming AsyncPopup works as implied) display a popup after 10 seconds, then every second onwards.  The wording in your question implies doing the opposite though (showing a popup then updating state on the main thread's object).

Comment: Check this out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SecondaryLoop.html

Comment: There is a main loop that is a simple counter.  I am trying to get input from a user without stopping the main loop.  The response from the dialog would affect the main loop.  In this example after 10 seconds a popup dialog appears without pausing the main loop (x==10).  It only appears when x==10.  I need the response from the dialog to determine if I need to reset the counter.  However I need the counter to continue while waiting for the response.  I will check out the link for SecondaryLoop that may solve my issue.

Comment: The SecondaryLoop doesn't seem like it allows Async?

Answer (score 0):

Your first "rough example" is not so far away from a working solution (if I correctly understood the question):

- Add a `reset()` method to your `MyTask` class that does whatever should happen if the user decides to reset.
- Add a constructor to your `AsyncPopUp` class that expects a `MyTask` object as argument and save it to a field `task`.
- When you do `new AsyncPopUp` in your `MyTask` class, pass `this` as constructor argument
- Where you do `System.out.println("Send Message to task to reset")` call `task.reset()`.

By the way: Note that `if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)` looks nicer than `if (response == 0)`… ;-)